# Create a third csv with rows from one csv that are not present in another csv

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I want to create a new csv "Result.csv" which contains rows from one csv "New.csv" which are not present in another csv "Old.csv".

For example,

**Old.csv**

john   Michigan   2018

ron     Michigan   2018

jane    Ohio         2017

**New.csv**

john    Michigan   2018

jane    Ohio          2017

ron      Michigan   2017

jack     New York  2018

**Result.csv**

ron      Michigan   2017

jack     New York  2018

I tried the following code in python, that I had read on another question but that doesn't seem to work, and gives me the wrong output. Is there something wrong with the below code? Any other alternative to the below code? Pandas could be an option?

```
with open('Old.csv', 'r') as f1:
    old = f1.readlines()

with open('New.csv', 'r') as f2:
    new = f2.readlines()

result = open("Result.csv", "w+")

for data in new:

    if data not in old:
        result.write(data)
result.close()
```

Comment: What is the "the wrong output" ?

Comment: @blueCat

With this example, it gives me:

john,Michigan,2018
jane,Ohio,2017
ron,Michigan,2017
jack,New York,2018

Comment: You may have some white space differences between files

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that:

**old.csv**

```
john,Michigan,2018
ron,Michigan,2018
jane,Ohio,2017
```

**new.csv**

```
john,Michigan,2018
jane,Ohio,2017
ron,Michigan,2017
jack,New York,2018
```

---

Using only `pandas` :

```
import pandas as pd

#open old csv as dataframe
old_df=pd.read_csv("old.csv",header=None)
#open new csv as dataframe
new_df=pd.read_csv("new.csv",header=None)
#join them
join_df=old_df.append(new_df,ignore_index=True)
#remove all duplicates
result_df=join_df.drop_duplicates(subset=None,keep=False)
#remove all present in old
result_df = result_df[~result_df.isin(old_df)].dropna()
#change float year to int
result_df[2] = result_df[2].astype(int)
#save as csv
result_df.to_csv("result.csv",header=None,index=None)
```

which give:

**result.csv**

```
ron,Michigan,2017
jack,New York,2018
```

Comment: +1
Seems to work great with the example CSVs. Didn't work with the CSVs I wanted to use this on. Probably some issue with my CSVs. Will check. Thanks! :)